# Laravel Highcharts - Cant set value and labels from arrays

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts, laravel-5.4

So I have 2 arrays "$resX' and "$rexY" and I want to use them for my values and labels for my line graph.

I have everything working so the arrays are displaying the correct information ("kind of") and the graph if the values set statically is displaying but not with my data.

My controller

```
    $user = User::findOrFail($talentId);
    $results = $user->performance;
    $resultsSorted = $results->sortBy('created_at');
    $resY = $resultsSorted
        ->groupBy(function ($result, $key) {
            return $result->created_at->format('wD');
        })
        ->map(function ($result) {
            return ($result->sum('answer'));
        });

    $i = 0;

    foreach($resY as $key = $label){
        $i++;


        $label = "W".$i;

    }

      $chartOne = Charts::create('area', 'highcharts')
        ->title('User Results')
        ->elementLabel('points')
        ->labels([$label])
        ->values([$resY])
        ->responsive(true);
```

Basically what I'm trying to get is for the label will print out "W1" then W2 etc..

I have the sum value figured out but struggling for the label

So my question is:

1. How do I get $label to display W1, W2 for each value

Answer (score 0):

Very simple to figure out, thought I'd give the answer incase someone needs it in the future. Just added the variable $week

```
    $i = 0;
    $week = "";

    foreach($resY as $key => $label){
        $i++;

        $week[] = "W" . $i;

    }
```

Now just add $week to the label on the chart

```
    $chartOne = Charts::create('area', 'highcharts')
        ->title('Talents Progress')
        ->elementLabel('+points')
        ->labels($week)
        ->values($resY)
        ->responsive(true);
```